# Мультиплеер, сервер-клиент на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу сделать игру "Камень, ножницы, бумага" с мультиплеером для ознакомления с сетевым взаимодействием. Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть. Нужно, например, фиксировать bool переменные каждого игрока, нажал ли "Готов" и т.д. Где эти общие переменные создавать?
PS. Думаю подойдет пример с онлайн Шашками.

Comment: Сервер можно написать на си или си++, про это дело есть книги.

Comment: Google + "Unity network" = https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html

Comment: а нельзя сделать хостом игрока, который создал и он ждет, когда к нему подключится другой чел (клиент)?

Comment: maq, можно. Читай мануал.